# Displaying json data in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I would like to display data returned from service call into view:

**Service Code** :

```
.service('HomeExchangeList', function ($rootScope, $http, $log) {
    this.getHomeExchange = function() {
        var rates = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/feeds/homerates_android.php'
        }).success(function (data) {
            $log.log(data);
            return data;

        });

        return homeRates;
    };
})
```

**JSON Data returned by service**

```
            {
               "record":[
                  {
                     "Name":"GBP\/USD",
                     "Ticker":"GBP\/USD",
                     "Price":"0.5828",
                     "Open":"0.5835",
                     "High":"0.5848",
                     "Low":"0.5828",
                     "PercentagePriceChange":"0.1371",
                     "Movement":"0.0800",
                     "DateStamp":"2014\/07\/09",
                     "TimeStamp":"22:15:00"
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"EUR\/USD",
                     "Ticker":"EUR\/USD",
                     "Price":"0.7330",
                     "Open":"0.7344",
                     "High":"0.7351",
                     "Low":"0.7327",
                     "PercentagePriceChange":"0.2585",
                     "Movement":"0.1900",
                     "DateStamp":"2014\/07\/09",
                     "TimeStamp":"22:15:00"
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"GHS\/USD",
                     "Ticker":"GHS\/USD",
                     "Price":"3.3350",
                     "Open":"3.2650",
                     "High":"3.3500",
                     "Low":"3.2650",
                     "PercentagePriceChange":"0.8915",
                     "Movement":"3.0000",
                     "DateStamp":"2014\/07\/09",
                     "TimeStamp":"22:15:00"
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"KES\/USD",
                     "Ticker":"KES\/USD",
                     "Price":"87.7000",
                     "Open":"86.2970",
                     "High":"87.6500",
                     "Low":"86.1800",
                     "PercentagePriceChange":"0.0661",
                     "Movement":"5.8000",
                     "DateStamp":"2014\/07\/09",
                     "TimeStamp":"22:15:00"
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"MUR\/USD",
                     "Ticker":"MUR\/USD",
                     "Price":"30.2925",
                     "Open":"29.1460",
                     "High":"29.4300",
                     "Low":"29.0500",
                     "PercentagePriceChange":"-0.0909",
                     "Movement":"-2.7500",
                     "DateStamp":"2014\/07\/09",
                     "TimeStamp":"22:15:00"
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"MWK\/USD",
                     "Ticker":"MWK\/USD",
                     "Price":"393.5000",
                     "Open":"393.3900",
                     "High":"393.3900",
                     "Low":"385.0000",
                     "PercentagePriceChange":"-0.2548",
                     "Movement":"-100.0000",
                     "DateStamp":"2014\/07\/09",
                     "TimeStamp":"22:15:00"
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"NGN\/USD",
                     "Ticker":"NGN\/USD",
                     "Price":"162.3000",
                     "Open":"160.0600",
                     "High":"162.4000",
                     "Low":"160.0600",
                     "PercentagePriceChange":"0.2459",
                     "Movement":"40.0000",
                     "DateStamp":"2014\/07\/09",
                     "TimeStamp":"22:15:00"
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"ZAR\/USD",
                     "Ticker":"ZAR\/USD",
                     "Price":"10.6659",
                     "Open":"10.6751",
                     "High":"10.7162",
                     "Low":"10.6523",
                     "PercentagePriceChange":"0.9840",
                     "Movement":"10.6000",
                     "DateStamp":"2014\/07\/09",
                     "TimeStamp":"22:15:00"
                  },
                  {
                     "Name":"ZMK\/USD",
                     "Ticker":"ZMK\/USD",
                     "Price":"47.7014",
                     "Open":"47.3850",
                     "High":"47.7000",
                     "Low":"46.8900",
                     "PercentagePriceChange":"0.0067",
                     "Movement":"0.3165",
                     "DateStamp":"2013\/07\/27",
                     "TimeStamp":"01:55:00"
                  }
               ]
            }
```

**Controller code**

```
function HomeCtrl($scope, Page, $location, HomeExchangeList) {

    $scope.rates = HomeExchangeList.getHomeExchange();
    $scope.$on('HomeExchangeList', function (event, data) {
        $scope.exchangeRates = data;
    });
}
```

**View**

```
<ul id="home-rates"  ng-repeat="rate in exchangeRates">
    <li><span class='rate-symbol'>{{rate.Name}}</span><span class='rate-amount'>{{rate.Price}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to display the data returned by in the service in the view but it doesn't seem to be working. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) invocations all return a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q), not the result of your request. Your service should just return the result of the `$http` call, and your controller needs to attach a `.success` handler to receive the data and set it on the scope of your controller.

```
.service('HomeExchangeList', function ($rootScope, $http, $log) {
    this.getHomeExchange = function() {
        var rates = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/feeds/homerates_android.php'
        }).success(function (data) {
            $log.log(data);
            // removed your return data; it doesn't do anything, and this success is only added to log the result. if you don't need the log other than for debugging, get rid of this success handler too.   
        });

        return rates;
    };
})


function HomeCtrl($scope, Page, $location, HomeExchangeList) {
    HomeExchangeList.getHomeExchange().success(function(data) {
        $scope.exchangeRates = data;
    });
}
```

Second, the root of your JSON is not an array, so you can't enumerate through just `exchangeRates` alone. Perhaps you meant `exchangeRates.record`.

Comment: Thank.. this is working to a certain extent but the resulting exchangeRates.record used in ng-repeat="rate in exchageRates.record" is only displaying one record. Am i mission something??

Comment: @munya.nyika See the demo I put together here http://plnkr.co/edit/oJPLZUpzYG3NEwsf1G9M?p=preview and compare my service and controller declarations in scripts.js to yours, as well as the HTML in my index to yours. It works as I described once you change your repeater to use `exchangeRates.record` (alternately, you could just assign `$scope.exchangeRates = demo.record;` in your controller).

Answer (score 0):

try to assign data.record to $scope.exchangeRates instead of data... as data doesnt hold the array of records... it holds record which then holds the array

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your service function always returns undefined:

```
var rates = ...,
return homeRates;
```

It should be

```
return rates;
```

Second, once that is fixed, the service doesn't return data. It returns a promise, and you can't iterate on a promise. What you need in the controller is:

```
HomeExchangeList.getHomeExchange().then(function(data) {
    $scope.rates = data.record;
}
```

The call to $scope.$on doesn't make any sense. $scope.$on is used to listen for events. Not to get data from a promise.

And finally, your view must iterate over these retes, and not over exchangeRates:

```
ng-repeat="rate in rates">
```